# calling function in onopen event of websocket in React.js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I am using websocket in React.js component, and trying to call a local method `register` in `onopen` event of websocket. `console.log()` is working ok inside onopen event, but my local function `register` is not. I am getting errror *register is not a function*.

Here is the code

```
this.ws.onopen = function()
{
  console.log('Connected! now registering');
  this.register();
}
```

Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the value of `this` is changing. What's happening is you're assigning a function to `this.ws.onopen`, and then the web socket instance is invoking `onopen` where `this` points to the web socket itself, and not your reactjs class instance. You need to preserve a reference to your reactjs class instance and use that to invoke the `register` method:

```
this.ws.onopen = () =>
{
  console.log('Connected! now registering');
  this.register();
}
```

The above uses arrow functions (an ECMA6 feature) to preserve the value of this. This works because arrow functions don't allow their caller (in this case the web socket) to change their value of `this`. Or you can do:

```
var self = this;
this.ws.onopen = function()
{
  console.log('Connected! now registering');
  self.register();
}
```

which simply stores a reference to your reactjs object prior to executing the function where the value for `this` gets changed. Or you can do:

```
this.ws.onopen = function()
{
  console.log('Connected! now registering');
  this.register();
}.bind(this)
```

which, prior to assigning a function to the property `this.ws.onopen` asserts that no matter who or how the function is called, the value of `this` for the function will always be whatever you passed to `.bind`.